Blazor Web App NavigationManager in Client -> Exception_WasThrown
I was creating a Blazor Web App using VS2022. Here is the project overview:

When using the NavigationManager in the code section of the Client project I get an Exception_WasThrown error:

Here is the Home.razor content in BlazorApp.Client:
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/weather");
    }
}

I already added this:
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
        .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp1.Client._Imports).Assembly);

to Program.cs in the BlazorApp project and I have updated my Routes.razor in the Client project as follows:
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

Anything I am missing here?
Thanks!
I was trying adding the assembly to the Project.cs as well as the Route.razor according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

May I kno why you moved the Route.razor  Home.razor Weather.razor and maybe some other components into .Clent project? By default these are put in the Server side  project. And you are trying to work on Navigation, may I know what you are trying to achieve?

@TinyWang, if you use the most recent Blazor Web App template and select "Interactivity location" to be "Global", all these razor files are in the .Client project.

I can reproduce your issue in my side, and after it's blocked by this exception, I press F5 to continue the program, it  can still navigate to weather component, so that I'm afraid this is due to pre-render. But even if I set @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)) in the component, the issue still exist.

May I know whether you tried to put the navigation into OnAfterRender event instead of OnInitialized if you had the same symptom with me? Can you try protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender){if (firstRender){NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/weather");}}?

I find a similar case here which having the same exception and the app can also continue to run. I think it's caused by conflict between rendering and navigation(try to navigation when component hasn't  completed rendering). That's why I asked you to try OnAfterRender.

That has fixed it, thank you @TinyWang!

Thank you for your kind reply, I summarized our discussion and post the answer below. Please feel free to let me know if it still has other issues.

Get confirmation from OP, using OnAfterRender instead of OnInitialized could solve the issue. Based on my test, when the exception occurred, I can press F5 to continue to run the application and the navigation will complete finally, so that I'm afraid the exception is somewhat similar to first-chance exception due to the conflict between initialization and rendering. So that using OnAfterRender can avoid this conflict.
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender){
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/weather");
    }
}

